# CXF client NTLM authentication on weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, cxf, ntlm

I am developing a sharepoint web service client with Apache CXF and I am having a lot of problems with the NTLM authentication when the client runs on the weblogic server.

If I run a simple test on Eclipse, the code works perfectly, but If I run the same code on a web application deployed on weblogic 10.3.6, the NTLM authentication fails and sends the following error:

```
org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '401: Unauthorized' when communicating with http://win-server-2008/sitios /sitio_registro/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

I don't know what could be the difference between running the same code on a test and on a web application deployed on weblogic. Any idea?

The authentication code snipet is:

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(listsSoap);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        if (http instanceof AsyncHTTPConduit) {
            AsyncHTTPConduit conduit = (AsyncHTTPConduit) http;
            DefaultHttpAsyncClient defaultHttpAsyncClient;
            try {
                defaultHttpAsyncClient = conduit.getHttpAsyncClient();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }

            Credentials credentials = new NTCredentials( conexionSharepointConfigVO.getUser(), conexionSharepointConfigVO.getPwd(), "", "" );

            defaultHttpAsyncClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials( AuthScope.ANY,credentials);

            ((BindingProvider) listsSoap).getRequestContext().put(Credentials.class.getName(), credentials);
        }
```

UPDATE: I tested the same code in Tomcat 6.0.43 and it works ok.

Comment: What account is your WebLogic process running as?

Comment: A windows administrator account, but I realized I does not start weblogic  as administrator. Is it possible to start weblogic as administrator?

Comment: How are you starting the server? Are you running as a Windows service or from the command line?

Comment: I am starting weblogic from the command line

Comment: In that case, WebLogic should start under whatever user that you are logged into the server with. Is that not what you are seeing?

Comment: On the windows machine the java process where weblogic runs belongs to my windows user.

Comment: On the linux machine, the java process belongs to the linux user who starts the proccess.

Comment: @DavidGarcíaGonzález did you ever solve this? Stuck with the same problem. Authenticating against NTLM from Java works fine a standalone app and in a webapp deployed to Tomcat but it fails if deployed in Weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a Windows service setting the service to run under the desired account or use the "Run as different user" option when opening the command prompt so WebLogic will start from the command line as the desired user.